# ¿Como insertar el id de la data? pero que me muestre el nombre en el select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

En el select ya muestro el nombre de la data 'json', pero quiero mandar a la db su id.

```
 <section class="col col-6">
  <label class="label"> Nombre </label>
   <select name="room_id" id="room_id" class="form-control">
   </select>      
 </section>
```

```js
$.each(data.room_options, function(key, value) {   
     $('#room_id')
         .append($("<option/>")
               .attr("value",key.room_options)
               .text(value.name));                        
     $('#room_id').select2();
});
```

Comment: podrías mostrar qué estructura tiene data.room_options

Comment: Por lo que veo, quieres llevar un select con las opciones de `data.room_options`. Entonces, ¿cuál es el problema? No puedes solo poner código y esperar que alguien como por arte de magia entienda **a la perfección** lo que tratas de hacer y te ayude a resolver el problema. Provee detalles por favor. Empieza por [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/54272/edit) respondiendo a la pregunta de @amenadiel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con con esto logré lo que quería

```
.text(value.name).val(value.id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Que tal, creo que esto es lo que querias lograr.

```js
var data = {}

data.room_options = {
  "Single": "habitación simple",
  "Double": "habitacion doble"
}

$.each(data.room_options, function(key, value) {   
     $('#room_id')
         .append($("<option>")
               .attr("value",key.room_options)
               .text(value));                        
     $('#room_id').val("habitacion doble");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <section class="col col-6">
  <label class="label"> Nombre </label>
   <select name="room_id" id="room_id" class="form-control">
   </select>      
 </section>
```

Comment: creo que el valor de cada option tiene que ser sólo `key`

Comment: Ya lo tengo así en el select2, muestro el nombre, lo que quiero lograr es insertar el 'id' porque así como esta inserta el 'nombre'.

Comment: Quieres insertar el Id del select dentro del la etiqueta de "option" ?

Comment: Si, mi data trae esto ` description: ""
id: "24"
med: null
name: "Test" `  el name lo muestro, pero quiero inserar el id

Comment: Podrias expicarte mejor ? y colocar un ejemplo de la data que tienes para poder revisarla, porque en el ejemplo que mostre arriba solo hay un objeto con varios atributos.

Según veo creo que lo que quieres lograr es que el objeto que tiene la data tiene varios objetos dentro y cada uno tiene un ID y quieres insertar ese ID en el select, no ?

Comment: Si ese data trae varios objetos, ya muestro el name en el select, pero lo que quiero lograr es mandar a la base de datos el id de ese objeto no el nombre.